# How to check if JWT token is expired in Angular 8

Tags: angular, jwt

In Angular 8 what are different ways to check if the JWT token has expired. The expiry time is 1 hour.
working code/samples will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I use this, it's really easy: https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt

Comment: you can use this package "https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode" and check the expiry time on `canActivate`

Answer (score 42):

**Option 1 - Manual**

Token expiry time is encoded in the token in [UTC time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) format. So it can be fetched and checked manually against current time in UTC. Try the following

```js
private tokenExpired(token: string) {
  const expiry = (JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]))).exp;
  return (Math.floor((new Date).getTime() / 1000)) >= expiry;
}

ngOnInit() {
  if (this.tokenExpired(token)) {
    // token expired
  } else {
    // token valid
  }
}
```

**Option 2 - Using `JwtHelperService`**

You could use the `JwtHelperService`'s [`isTokenExpired()`](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/blob/5ea47955ef9f3555412312001fd0a849245134fe/projects/angular-jwt/src/lib/jwthelper.service.ts#L142) method
from [`@auth0/angular-jwt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt) package to check if the token has expired already.

```js
import {JwtHelperService} from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
.
.
constructor(private jwtHelper: JwtHelperService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  if (this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) {
    // token expired 
  } else {
    // token valid
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Is option 2 i.e. using third party auth0 library a good solution?

Comment: @Southstar: A quick glance at the `isTokenExpired()`'s source shows it's more or less the same implementation as the manual. I'd using it is a matter of ones own opinion and convenience.

Answer (score 4):

You can get token expiry date with Angular-JWT package

```
 getTokenExpirationDate(token: string): Date {
    const decodedToken = helper.decodeToken(token);

    if (decodedToken.exp === undefined) { return null; }

    const date = new Date(0);
    date.setUTCSeconds(decodedToken.exp);
    return date;
  }
```

Comment: this throws an error now for angular 12, null is not assignable to type date

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something like this in my app and it works fine :

```
this.userToken$.pipe(
            filter((token: AuthToken) => !!token),
            map((token: AuthToken) => token.expiresIn()),
            tap((expiresIn: number) => console.log('token expires in', expiresIn / 1000 / 60, 'minutes')),
            switchMap((expiresIn: number) => timer(expiresIn)),
        ).subscribe(() => {
            console.warn('token expires');
            this.logout();
        });
```

This way, the user is not logged out once he tries to execute a new request but as soon as the token expires.

Comment: What is userToken$ there?

Comment: An observable of a custom object holding some infos about a JWT (expiration date, user id...). In my case, it is retrieved from the local storage.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const jwtToken = JSON.parse(atob(response.jwtToken.split('.')[1]));
    const expires = new Date(jwtToken.exp * 1000);
    const timeout = expires.getTime() - Date.now();
    setTimeout(() => this.logout(strategyName), timeout);
```

I implemented this using setTimeout and it will automatically logout when the token expires

Comment: `this.logout()` is not invoked. You need to pass it in as a function to be invoked: `setTimeout(function() { this.logout(strategyName); }, timeout);`

Answer (score 0):

Check if JWT token is expired using Angular JWT library

run command: `npm install @auth0/angular-jwt`

```
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

const helper = new JwtHelperService();
```

...

```
  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    return !helper.isTokenExpired(token);
  }
```

hope it helps.