# Can't call api again inside function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, request

I have a problem with requests.
The idea is that if request fail becouse token expired function will send login request (with data from session data) and will send original request again and return values.
I think there could be obvious resolution to this but I barely code in js.
Any idea how to fix it?

Code here:

```js
  apiCall(url, body, first = true) {

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('jwt')} `),
    };
    this.deleteNullParams(body);
    return this.httpClient.post(this.API_URL + url, body, httpOptions).pipe(
      map(response => {
        if (response['result'] != 'success' && first) {
          console.log("Failed");
          this.loginWithSessionData();
          return this.apiCall(url, body, false);
        }
        else {
          return response;
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

```
getLocationDetails(body) {
    return this.apiCall('/api/locationList', body);
  }
```

```
  loginWithSessionData() {
    let password = sessionStorage.getItem('password');
    let username = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
    if (password && password != '' && username && username != '') {
      const json = {};
      json['username'] = username;
      json['password'] = password;
      this.userLogin(json).subscribe((res: any) => {
        if (res['body']['result'] !== 'failed') {
          sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', res.body['data'].token);
          localStorage.setItem('login_data', JSON.stringify(res.body['data']));
          return true;
        }
      }, (error) => { });
    }
    else {
      sessionStorage.clear();
    }
    return false;
  }
```

So I want to return apiCall again after getting valid token, but for some reason any other request than login won't send in apiCall function.

**Edit**:  
To be more specific what happens when function is called:
try to get data, 
fails becouse of no(or expired) token, 
sends login request, gets it,
sets up token and thats it, 
any more request won't send till next refresh/change page.

**Answer**

Ok so the accepted answer is right just needed to add returns:

```
  apiCall(url, body, first = true) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('jwt')}`)
    };
    this.deleteNullParams(body);
  
    return this.httpClient.post(this.API_URL + url, body, httpOptions).pipe(
      switchMap((response: any) => {
        return iif(
          () => response['result'] != 'success' && first,
          this.loginWithSessionDataObs().pipe(switchMap(() => this.apiCall(url, body, false))),
          of(response)
        )
        
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: the problem is, that you're trying to run `this.apiCall(url, body, false);` before `this.loginWithSessionData();` has even had a chance to login - you'll need to wait for the login to finish before trying the api call again

Comment: I thought so but even if i set there 80 apiCall there is still only one request visible, why?

Comment: I don't know, it's a mystery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtaining values from observables are asynchronous, meaning you cannot expect to write some statements after the subscription callback and them *executed* after the callback. They will run earlier.

In your case you'd need to use multiple RxJS functions (`of`, `iif`) and operator (`switchMap`) to make it depend on each other.

```js
apiCall(url, body, first = true) {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('jwt')}`)
  };
  this.deleteNullParams(body);

  this.httpClient.post(this.API_URL + url, body, httpOptions);.pipe(
    switchMap((response: any) => {
      iif(
        () => response['result'] != 'success' && first,
        this.loginWithSessionData().pipe(switchMap(() => this.apiCall(url, body, false))),
        of(response)
      )
    })
  );
}

loginWithSessionData(): Observable<any> {     // <-- return observable here
  let username = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
  let password = sessionStorage.getItem('password');

  const storeData = (data: any) => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', data.body['data'].token);
    localStorage.setItem('login_data', JSON.stringify(data.body['data']));
  }

  return iif(
    () => (password && password != '' && username && username != ''),
    this.userLogin({ username: username, password: password }).pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        storeData(data);
        return true;
      })
    ),
    of(false).pipe(tap(() => sessionStorage.clear()))
  );
}
```

However, although it might work, I would say there might be a better way to re-trigger the HTTP request instead of the recursive call. For example, you could check the [token expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60758392/6513921) without triggering the HTTP request initially.

Comment: I think it could be better, but it's not real jwt it's just named this way, I'm editing somebody else code.
Anyway, the code you write looks good however login don't works as I intended

Comment: @zywy: That's a shame. You could nevertheless try to decode the token to find some way of expiration timestamp. Try to use some tool like [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)

Comment: Sure but in fact it's the same. I'm not triggering request but after every just check if it faild becouse of token (later will add response codes so I'll be sure it's becouse of token) and only then I'll send login request. And in that case I don't even have to decode it, I could just save the time of last login and I know token lifespan so it would be easy to cal that.