# How to Check JWT token expiration before calling Api from Angular to .NET-core

Tags: c#, angular, jwt, refresh-token

I am using angular as a client and asp.net-core as a server. From server I am creating JWT token and refresh token and passing it to angular and storing it in localstorage. I am putting my JWT token validation for 5 minutes and refresh token as 2 days . The issue which I am facing is that my token is expire and I am on page where only authenticate user can visit who have valid jwt token until I refresh my page or go to another URL my auth is not going to come into picture and will not get to know that our token is expire so if there is a event in which we make call to [authorize]Api our call will going to reject because of we having a expired token . So **I want to know is there any way to check that is token expire before making any call to server api**

here is my **AuthGurd**

```
  constructor (private _authService: AuthService, private _router: Router) {}

  async canActivate(): Promise<boolean>{
    if(await this._authService.isUserAuthenticated() === true){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      this._router.navigate([RouteConstant.SIGN_IN]);
      return false;
    }
  }
public async isUserAuthenticated(): Promise<boolean>{
    if(this._storageService.getToken() !== null){
      if(!this._jwtHelperService.isTokenExpired(this._storageService.getToken()?.toString())){
        return true;
      }
      else{
        if(!this._storageService.refreshTokenExists()){
          return false;
        }
        else{
          let authTokenClient: AuthTokenClient = {
            token: this._storageService.getToken() as string,
            refreshToken: this._storageService.getRefreshToken() as string
          };
            return await this.refreshAuthToken(authTokenClient);
            !this._jwtHelperService.isTokenExpired(this._storageService.getToken()?.toString());
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }
  }

  public setAuth(authToken: AuthToken){
    this._storageService.saveToken(authToken.token?.toString());
    this._storageService.saveRefreshToken(authToken.refreshToken);
  }
  public async refreshAuthToken(authTokenClient: AuthTokenClient) {
    const response = await this._http.post<AuthToken>(environment.apiHost + UrlConstant.ACCOUNT_REFRESH, authTokenClient,{observe: 'response'}).toPromise();
    console.log(response);
    const newToken = (<any>response).body.token;
            console.log(newToken);
            const newRefreshToken = (<any>response).body.refreshToken;
            console.log(newRefreshToken);
            localStorage.setItem("token", newToken);
            localStorage.setItem("refreshToken",newRefreshToken);
            if (newToken && newRefreshToken == null){
              return false
            }
            else {
              return true;
            }
  }
  
  
}
```

I tried to validate the jwt token before every call to api i have done that by
here my
**app.component.ts**

```
async clickEvent(){
    if (await this._authService.isUserAuthenticated()==true)
    return this.api();
  else{
    this.logout();
  }
}
  public api(){
    this._http.get("http://localhost:15363/WeatherForecast").subscribe(response => {
 console.log(response);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err)
    });
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
    <button  (click)="clickEvent()" >
        Click Me</button>
</div>
```

**c#** code Api which angular is calling

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
```

But I think this is not best approach for one call it's will valid but in application we have many calls we cannot every time use this if else statement

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially decode the JWT Token, which in theory will include the expiration timestamp of the Token.

Try and decode an example of one of your tokens here: https://jwt.io/ and see if there's a property included for the expiration time.

There are some good answers here on how to handle this best:

[How to check if JWT token is expired in Angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60758154/how-to-check-if-jwt-token-is-expired-in-angular-8)

Answer (score 0):

**OPTIMIZATION**

When an access token is received from the Authorization Server, the JSON response includes an `expires_in` field. This can potentially be used by a client to silently renew access tokens, via some kind of background timer or thread.

**RELIABLE OPTION**

All OAuth clenits should deal with 401 responses from APIs by trying to get a new access token, then retrying the API call - see [this Curity API Client class](https://github.com/curityio/web-oauth-via-bff/blob/main/code/spa/src/api/apiClient.ts#L25) for an example. It may be needed for reasons like this:

- Clock differences between API and Authorization Server
- Token signing certificate renewal
- Certain infrastructure setups I could describe

**TRY THE RELIABLE OPTION**

Sign in to my online Single Page App on my [Quick Start Page](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/), then click the `Expire Access Token` and `Reload Data` buttons. Slowdown should not be noticeable to the end user and renewal should only be needed on a small percentage of API requests. Consider using an access token lifetime a little longer - perhaps 15 minutes.

**SUMMARY**

In all of my years of working with OAuth I have used the reliable option and never bothered with the optimization. This has also kept my code simple.